# listView having link of webpage as a item of that list

Tags: android

How to add Links on ListView in android? i.e. whenever if I select a list item it open a relative website. for Example I have a list in which there are some items like google,fb,twitter. whenever I click on google it will open google home page and so on.

this is my code please suggest me some code to do this task.

```
String[] names = new String[] {"Dainik Bhaskar","google"}; 
ListView lv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, names);
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adpt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,R.id.webView1,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(names[pos].equals("Dainik Bhasker"))
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.bhaskar.com")));
    }
    else if(names[pos].equals("google"))
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got any error?

Comment: There is no problem in code then whats the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's your complete code I don't see:
Where you get reference to the `ListView` with `findViewById(R.id.YOUR_LIST_ID)`.

See an example of `ListView` [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, you just have to add the property [android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) to the TextView associated with listview item.